# The error and error-code tag should be merged

Tags: discussion

The [error](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error) and [error-code](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-code) tags should be merged.

The canonical tag should be [error](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error) because [error-code](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-code) only has 2 questions, and [error](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error) is shorter.

Comment: Tag synonyms are usually for things that mean the same thing.   An error is not the same as an error code.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Correct, but the questions currently using the tag [tag:error-code] don't specifically have something to do with an error code.

Comment: Then the correct thing to do would be to edit those questons and change the tag to "error" for those two questions

Comment: I disagree about them not being related to error codes.  The error codes for the two questions are "404" and "6" respectively

Answer (score 1):

`Error codes` could be considered a subset (i.e., an indication) of `errors`, specifically in regards to HTTP errors. *Errors* are much more encompassing and could refer to really any sort of error however, be it an application error or otherwise...

Therefore these two tags should remain un-unmerged, even if one was used much less. However, as with many tags on this site, we really could use a wiki summary for both the [error](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/540) an [error-code](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/1418) tags, for which a shiny new badge would be awarded for the effort, and you'd show up on [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/tag-editor) list :-)

More wiki summaries would really help clarify which tags to use and search on, and likely result in less confusion in cases like this where the user might just select both since they seem to be similar.